# Free Disk-Space Bar on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is anyone of you aware if there is such a Control you could use in you own projects. Just like the iTunes "used space" or Mac OS X "used disk space bar?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's typically a custom control.

That kind of stuff is usually done by creating a subclass of `NSView`, and overriding the `drawRect:` method, to create the custom component.

You can then create your shapes and fills the way you want.
Refer to the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more infos and examples.

Basic example to get you started:

```
- ( void )drawRect: ( NSRect )rect
{
    NSBezierPath * path;
    NSGradient   * gradient;
    CGFloat        radius;

    path     = [ NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rect xRadius: 2.0 yRadius: 2.0 ];
    gradient = [ [ NSGradient alloc ] initWithColorsAndLocations:   [ NSColor whiteColor ], 0.0,
                                                                    [ NSColor blackColor ], 1.0,
                                                                    nil
               ];

    [ gradient drawInBezierPath: path angle: -90 ];
    [ gradient release ];
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i've been thinking about, i also started developing such a component, seems to me as if there is no such component around github etc.

Comment: @kimar, please consider publishing your custom control on https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ when you have a working version.